# &:hover with Sass not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm using SASS with bootstrap to create a nav here and can't quite get the pseudo class for hover to work, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Clients</a></li>
                <li class="logo"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS/SASS here:

```
.navbar {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    padding-top: 3em;
    .navbar-nav {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        text-align: center;
        a {
            width: 8em;
            font-family: 'Allan', cursive;
            font-size: 2em;
            &:hover {
                color: #f00;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm being told I need to add more detail because my post is mostly code so I'm just adding this sentence.

Comment: can you post your html also?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not an appropriate description of the problem.  What doesn't work?  Did you look at the compiled CSS to see if it has the result you expected?  Is there an error?

Comment: Your code works fine, see here .. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWGevK

Comment: @cimmanon checking the compiled css always works because it shows you what selector is being created when using scss selectors etc... good advice.

Answer (score 6):

Your SASS code is working, but Bootstrap have defined this rule:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover{
    color: #333;
}
```

So you need to set a rule more specific than it, example adding `li` before `a` in the cascade chain:

```
.navbar {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    padding-top: 3em;
    .navbar-nav {
        display: inline-block;
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        text-align: center;
        li{
            a {
                width: 8em;
                font-family: 'Allan', cursive;
                font-size: 2em;
                &:hover {
                    color: #f00;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/3Logttdz/2/)

Or use `!important`, like:

```
&:hover {
    color: #f00 !important;
}
```

[**DEMO2**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/3Logttdz/1/)

Comment: It would be better to override the rule using the cascade rather than using `!important`

Comment: @Paulie_D I agree with you :)

Answer (score 5):

```
.classname {
    margin:50px;
    color:white;
    &:hover {
        color:red;
    }
}
```